# Voltar para a tela anterior após cadastro usando Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Tenho uma tela onde recebo um parâmetro (id) e a partir dele monto um formulário. Após salvar esse *form* preciso voltar para a tela anterior, para exibir o que foi salvo. Como posso fazer isso? Já tentei de várias formas, vários *Requests* mas nada funciona.

Formulário:

```
<form name="cad_user" id="cad_user" action="/user/novo" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">

                <input type="hidden" id="txtCadUsrId" value="">                            
                <label for="txtEdtUsrNomTop">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                <label>Senha</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control">
                <label>Repita a senha</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" class="form-control">
                <input type="hidden" name="codCliente" id="codCliente" value="<?php echo $clientes['cliente']->id ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button id="Cadastro"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

*Action* que cadastra no banco:

```
public function action_novo(){
    $cliente = ORM::factory('cliente');        
    $cliente->nomeCliente = $this->request->post('nomeCliente');
    $cliente->cnpjCliente = $this->request->post('cnpjCliente');
    $cliente->dataCadastro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if($cliente->save()){
        $session = Session::instance();
        $session->set('msg', 'Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!');            
        $this->redirect('admin/listClient');            
    }

}
```

Comment: Com salvar, poderia ser no submit do form?

Comment: Como assim? Salvar salva normal, eu preciso que volte a tela anterior e liste tudo o que já foi salvo entende?

Comment: Mas esse form está num lightbox ou em outra página?

Comment: O form está numa modal, apos fazer o submit ele vai lá e salva, quando voltar , não preciso que a modal apareça

Comment: Um comando para dar um refresh serveria?

Comment: SIm sim, acredito que sim, pelo menos eu acho

Comment: Vou deixar uma resposta com um código.

Comment: Ok, ai eu testo

Answer (score 5):

Problema resolvido.

Coloquei esse código na action:

```
HTTP::redirect('admin/detailClient/'.$this->request->post('codCliente'));
```

Comment: eu ia dizer pra você colocar isso onclick="window.location.reload()", mas deixa pra lá :).

Comment: Beleza amigo, de qualquer forma muito obrigado

Comment: Você pode marcar sua resposta como aceita, clicando no sinal de ticar embaixo dos pontos da resposta.